# getting more then 1 data from other tables while joining them

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, inner-join

[image: screenshot of the query]

I think the screenshot of the query is pretty much self-explanatory.

What I need, is simply to get 2 addresses from CustomerAddresses table instead of only 1 like in this example. **1 for ShippingAddress and the other for BillingAddress.**

It sounds like It's quite easy to solve this but obviously I'm missing something. Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to join the table that contains the addresses twice. Once for `ShippingAddressID` and once for `BillingAddressID`:

```
SELECT
    ...
    ShippingAddress.Address as 'ShippingAddress',
    BillingAddress.Address as 'BillingAddress',
    ...
FROM
    ...
    INNER JOIN CustomerAddresses as ShippingAddress
      ON Orders.ShippingAddressID = ShippingAddress.CustomerAddressID
    INNER JOIN CustomerAddresses as BillingAddress
      ON Orders.BillingAddressID = BillingAddress.CustomerAddressID
```